# Careers dropping state

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'll be the first to admit my state is not the most beautiful, clean, nor wealthy among the states of Germany, but is living in North Rhine-Westphalia such an embarrassment that it needs to be hidden completely?

[image]

[image]

if it is, then at least remove the second comma! :)

Comment: Hm, while we have you here, how would someone in Germany typically write that?  I assume "Cologne, Germany", not "Cologne, North Rhine-Wesphalia, Germany" (as we do in some places)?

Comment: @David `Cologne, Germany` will do fine. We do not have the habit of adding the state name. But maybe adding it wouldn't hurt in a careers context, though, to provide some orientation for foreigners?

Comment: I think a lot of region hierarchies throw in the extra level because there are some duplicates otherwise, e.g. we have several [towns/villages called Whitchurch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitchurch) in the UK. They're pretty unwieldly. I get annoyed having to write London, Greater London, UK.

Comment: @Rup: Great Britain, Greater London... sounds like a mania.

Comment: North-Rhine-Westphalia is really more of a *state of mind*, that's why.

Comment: @status-declined ohhhh boy, that it is!   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cologne_Carnival

Comment: @Developer Art:  Look, they just want you to know they're Great, OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  Sadly, prospective employers will have to do a bit more research to discover that Cologne is, in fact, in North Rhine-Westphalia.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they thought they did you a favor. Everyone knows those weird people of NRW - they like to dress strangely, then at one day they gather all together and drink and dance and do other unspeakable things. Better keep it quiet.

:)

What surprises me in the whole story is this:

[image]

Where are all those employers? Is careers THAT US-centric that in 2 months only one employer came by? Or is that everyone laughs when they see the location of Stuttgart? Those Swabian programmers you know. But I'm not even German, I seriously can program, I really do.

Comment: Naaah, the swabian engineer is one of the pillars of the nation! That can't be it. It's probably that careers *is* terribly US-centric, at least at the moment.